# Adverb in a introductory clause

Tags: adverbs

I have stumbled upon this sentence:

> But **more pragmatically**, the discipline encourages students to analyze complex material, question conventional beliefs, and express thoughts in a concise manner.

Ok so the first thing I understand is how is this:

> But more pragmatically

part of the sentence called? Is this a subordinate clause or how would it be called and why is it grammatically correct?

Now what confuses me is that it is correct. I was given the option to replace this "But more pragmatically" with

> But in a more pragmatic way,

But the answer explanation stated that "But more pragmatically" was correct. How is that correct? Isn't an adverb supposed to modify a verb? So then what is pragmatically modifying?

Comment: Confusingly (for what follows), your example uses the word 'pragmatically'. Here, it is the -ly relative of the usual non-linguistic sense of 'pragmatic': '_pragmatic_: dealing with things sensibly and realistically in a way that is based on practical rather than theoretical considerations' {[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pragmatic)}. // But your introductory phrase is a _double pragmatic marker_ (standing apart from the grammar of the matrix sentence). The 'but' (here) is a contrastive marker and the 'more pragmatically' is a restructuring and domain-indicating marker.

Comment: So this "but more pragmatically" is more like a comment but not a modifier? Is there a name to this phrase so I could do more research into?

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth thank you for the explanation. I see it now: you mean this in the sense "more pragmatically speaking, the discipline..." or "with a more pragmatic effect, the discipline..." where the whole statement that follows is considered "more pragmatic" by the narrator. I *have now deleted my first 2 comments* to avoid misleading other readers as to what the adverb actually modifies.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Fascinating.  Please, could you put that into an answer?  But -- I would suggest omitting the "Here, it is the -ly relative" sentence, as there is really no need here to make that distinction.